# Headless Chrome Selenium Code using Microsoft Azure VM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, virtual-machine

I am currently running Selenium script on a Microsoft Azure VM. If I don't put --headless as an argument, I receive the error "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)". However, when I add headless, my "browser.find_element("xpath"..." lines and "browser.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('input');") lines are no longer finds the element it found without the headless tag. Is there a way around this? When I try and print the source_code under the --headless tag, I get "You don't have permission to access <> on this server. Reference #18.76a83c17.1683142805.6dfb7eb"

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

        for i in range(5):
            browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
            browser.get('<insert browser>')
```

I tried to run it with "--headless" on my local and I run into the same issue. So I am wondering why that is and how to see what the html code is when I run headless. Thank you for any help.